# JLex Scanner Generating

Tags: java, parsing, lex

I'm using JLex for our latest assignment, attempting to generate a scanner for a language given to us by the professor.

At this point, I have the following written - assume the keywords and identifier rules are correct for the language we're working with.

```
import java.io.*;
%%
%{
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws java.io.IOException
    {
            MyLexer yy= new MyLexer(new FileReader("input"));
            while( yy.yylex() >= 0);
    }
%}

%integer
%class MyLexer
INT =int
KEYWORDS =IF|ELSE|WRITE|READ|RETURN|BEGIN|END|MAIN|INT|REAL
IDENTIFIER =[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*
%state COMMENT
%%
{KEYWORDS}
{
    System.out.println("keyword is .. " + yytext());
}
{IDENTIFIER}
{
    System.out.println("ID is .." + yytext());
}


\r\n|.|\n {}
```

Could anyone give some sort of hint or suggestion on how to:
1. detect comments (of the /* */ format)
2. count each occurrence of identifiers, keywords, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created the main method, you can also create member variables for you lexer in the lex file:

```
%{
private int keywordCount = 0;
public static void main(String argv[]) throws java.io.IOException
{
        MyLexer yy= new MyLexer(new FileReader("input"));
        while( yy.yylex() >= 0);
}
%}
```

Then you can increment keywordCount in the code associated with KEYWORDS:

```
{KEYWORDS}
{
System.out.println("keyword is .. " + yytext());
++keywordCount;
}
```

Detecting comments sounds like the main task for this homework assignment, so I'll leave that to you ;)

but I'll tell you that you should look into LEX / JFlex states.  You would detect a /* and then transition into a comment state.  When you detect */, while in the comment state, you would transition out of the comment state.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering about something like that. JLex confuses me as to where you can do Java and where you can't, but I guess that makes sense.
As for the commenting, I imagine the states you mentioned are probably what is being aimed at. It's not necessarily THE main task, but it's one of the "tricky" parts, so you're not far off. I will look into the states, thanks!